# Python : Appending items from 2D list to another 2D list at same indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, 2d

```
first_list=[[2,3],[],[1,3],[]]
second_list=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

I want to append the numbers of the first list to the second list at the same indexes. 
This should return:

```
[[1,2,3,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,1,3],[1,2,3]]
```

This seems complicated and I'm just a beginner at python.. please give me some help on how to approach this!

Comment: `[second_list[i] + first_list[i] for i in range(len(first_list))]`

Comment: `[a+b for a, b in zip(second_list, first_list)]`

Comment: `[el + first_list[idx] for idx, el in enumerate(second_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding the answer here:

```
[x+y for x,y in zip(second_list,first_list)]
```